# what does K in KMP_AFFINITY mean?

Tags: openmp

I just learned [KMP_AFFINITY](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/process-and-thread-affinity-for-intel-xeon-phi-processors-x200) from OpenMP. Could anyone tell me why its name starts with K? A lot of variables start with `KMP_` in Intel OpenMP implementation. Does it stand for kernel?

Comment: [I suspect it stands for KPTS](https://github.com/passlab/intel-openmp-runtime/blob/interop/src/kmp.h#L3). I have no idea what that stands for. Is there anything other than curiosity behind your question?

Comment: Just from curiosity. When I read to source code of OMP, there are lots of functions or variables starting with this prefix.

Answer (score 6):

Kuck, as in David Kuck's organization KAI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Kuck (disbanded subsequent to Kuck's retirement).